# Woocommerce; how to css right-align price?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been pounding my head anything solid all day trying to figure out the answer to this; I cannot for the life of me figure out how to right-align a price in a Woocommerce store I've built for a client.  Here's where I'm at:

```
.price .woocommerce-Price-amount {
    float: right !important;
    text-align: right !important;}
```

These don't seem to be working and I wonder if my theme (Avada) is some how overriding this?  Any help is appreciated.

Website:  https://shop.quarryoaks.com/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

**Solution #1**

```
.fusion-price-rating{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

**Solution #2**

```
.price {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Your solution #1 is what I came up with as well. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the help Juan and Justin!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it's only align price to the right. 
You're using flex with a column direction. So what you could do is increase this flex item (the price) to a full base width

```
.price {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arvie!  That Flex-Basis is what I was missing, something new to me.  Appreciate the help!